# Jasper subreport not getting datasourcebeans sub object property

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I am getting error in iReport when during subreport compilation:

```
Errors compiling E:\workspace_new\kidslake\src\main\resources\admissionForm_sub_1.jasper!
Compilation exceptions: com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.ErrorsCollector@28f84e61  
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: 
1. The method getFullName() is undefined for the type Object                 
value = ((java.lang.Object)field_director.getValue()).getFullName(); //$JR_EXPR_ID=17$                                                                       
2. The method getFullName() is undefined for the type Object                 
value = ((java.lang.Object)field_director.getOldValue()).getFullName(); //$JR_EXPR_ID=17$                                                                          
3. The method getFullName() is undefined for the type Object                 
value = ((java.lang.Object)field_director.getValue()).getFullName(); //$JR_EXPR_ID=17$                                                                       
3 errors      
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:204)     
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:512)     
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
```

My bean class is like

```
 class Mainclass{
     private List<AdmissionForm> admissionForm;
     //getter
     //setter
 }

 class AdmissionForm{
    private Director director;
    //getter
    //setter
 }

 class Director{
    private String fullName;
    //getter
    //setter
 }
```

I am passing `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` as list of `MainClass` in my main report

I defined subreport and pass field like
`new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{admissionFormList})`

I define to access director fullname property in my subreport

```
$F{director}.getFullName()
```

but when i compile main report or subreport getting the error above.

Help me to resolve my issue

Comment: Looks like something wrong with your subreport's template.  Do you have public getter for `Director.fullName`?

Comment: Yes i have public getter and setter

Comment: You should post the snippet of *jrxml* with fields declaration. Did you check solutions by data67?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

1. Set the type of the `director` report field to `Director` (full/qualified class name).  Apparently the current field type is `java.lang.Object`
2. Change the report language to Groovy.
3. Declare a report field called `director.fullName` and use the field directly instead of `$F{director}.getFullName()`